What am I doing wrong with the item separation argument in the \enumerate environment?
I wonder how one could reduce the space between items in the \enumerate (or \itemize, etc.) environment beyond what result from setting the \itemsep to 0, or removing it altogether with 'nosep' command in the enumitem package.  There is still a fair amount of space even with 'nosep'.
A MWE:
\documentclass{letter}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item Rocks. \\
\item Paper. \\
\item Scissors.
\end{enumerate}

\vspace{1in}

\begin{enumerate}[nosep]
\item Rocks. \\
\item Paper. \\
\item Scissors.
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}




do not use \\  at the end of items.

Wow, that simple!  Thanks.

As Ulrike says don't end items with \\, in general un-learn that you can use \\ (or similar) in the text of your document. You never need it, only use it to change row in alignment constructions. In general if you feel you need to use \\ in the text, you're doing something wrong.

OK, good to know, thank you.
